# Django not recognizing django admin urls

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I just registered my models my models with django admin. 
I navigate to the django admin at /admin. I log in sucessfully and I can see all my models. great so far.

But now if I try to click one of the links, for Ex: 'users', django gives me a 404 saying

```
The current URL, admin/auth/user/, didn't match any of these.
```

Its really weird because in my urls.py I have it mapped correctly

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

I have all the required middleware enabled and have these in my installed apps

```
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.admin',
```

anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this one in your urls.py?:

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()
```

But in fact without this you shouldn't even see models from django.contrib.auth... weird, can you post complete urls.pt file?

Comment: here it is

from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
import dselector
import splash.views
import hypervisor.views
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()
parser = dselector.Parser()


#hypervisor
urlpatterns = parser.patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

Comment: is this only urls file you use in the project?(there are no url patterns for your views)